# Vendor Listing by Location

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

I am trying to implement a solution provided at wcvendors.com knowledgebase and unable to get the indicated results. Can somebody help me with the implementation as to where this is going wrong. I am a beginner at wordpress and php.

Basically, I am trying to list vendors by their store location. For this i am using wc vendors multi vendor marketplace plugin. I have created a dropdown custom field as indicated in the code. The custom fields are coming up at the registration time and also reflected in the user profile for view and edit. I want to filter the vendors on this meta key to have vendors categorised by their location.

IF there is any other option to do that it would be a great thing.

Comment: Welcome to WPSE.  Thanks for a nice detailed question with a good sample of your code.  Given that your problem looks as though it needs knowledge of two particular third party plugins, it's likely the people here won't be able to help.  You might get quicker & better help by asking back at the vendor forum that your solution is taken from.  Please do review [ask]

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @Ravi This looks like you've added your question and answer together. To follow the format of this site you should use the `edit` link above and separate out the issue you were having - then, using the Answer box below ( yes, you can answer your own questions ) you may provide a solution and eventually accept it.

Comment: Sure Howdy, I am new to this place and would take care of that in future.

Comment: I have tried to check with the author of the code and haven't recd. a response for quite some time now. Hence, checking out in different forums.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another way I figured out is using custom taxonomies and product filter plugins.

Very simple and easy to implement in any part of the web page.

Comment: Please add your solution, including the code. Without that your answer isn't very helpful.

Comment: There is no special coding involved other than installing custom taxonomy plugin and woocommerce product filter plugins from the wordpress repository. The rest is matter of configuring and customising the required fields.

Answer (score 0):

Solution provided by Randall - http://www.wcvendors.com/help/topic/sort-vendor-by-shop-setting-field/

Overall, here is the concept. I needed a shortcode that would allow me to separate vendors by location. To do this, I required users to select a location during their registration and in their store settings. Then I pulled that meta info into a shortcode which filtered and displayed only those vendors.

Here is an example: [wc_vendors_location location=”Alabama”]

So here is how I set everything up. I use WP User Frontend Pro. Found here. This is important because that is how I attached the location meta to the vendor. So, here we go.

First I went into the registration form designated for my vendors settings page. (Please refer to this post here for that form) I added a dropdown with all the locations I needed my vendors to select. This is/was the easiest part.

Next I created this code:

```
/**
  *     list of vendors by location 
  * 
  *     @param $atts shortcode attributs 
*/
function wc_vendors_location( $atts ) {
    $html = ''; 

    extract( shortcode_atts( array(
            'orderby'       => 'display_name',
            'order'         => 'ASC',
            'per_page'      => '12',
            'columns'       => '4', 
            'show_products' => 'yes',
            'location'      => '',
            'org'           => '',
        ), $atts ) );
    // Hook into the user query to modify the query to return users that have at least one product 
    if ($show_products == 'yes') remove_action( 'pre_user_query', array( $this, 'vendors_with_products') );
    // Get all vendors 
    $vendor_total_args = array ( 
        'role'              => 'vendor', 
        'meta_key'          => 'pv_shop_slug', 
        'meta_value'        => '',
        'meta_key'          => 'location', 
        'meta_value'        => $location,
        'meta_key'          => 'organization', 
        'meta_value'        => $org,
        'orderby'           => $orderby,
        'order'             => $order,
    );
    if ($show_products == 'yes') $vendor_total_args['query_id'] = 'vendors_with_products'; 
    $vendor_query = New WP_User_Query( $vendor_total_args ); 
    $all_vendors =$vendor_query->get_results(); 

    ob_start();
    // Loop through all vendors and output a simple link to their vendor pages
    foreach ($all_vendors as $vendor) {
       wc_get_template( 'vendor-list.php', array(
                                            'shop_link'         => WCV_Vendors::get_vendor_shop_page($vendor->ID), 
                                                    'shop_name'         => $vendor->pv_shop_name, 
                                                    'vendor_id'         => $vendor->ID, 
                                                    'shop_description'  => $vendor->pv_shop_description, 
                                            ), 'wc-vendors/front/', wcv_plugin_dir . 'templates/front/' );
    } // End foreach 

    $html .= '<ul class="wcv_vendorslist">' . ob_get_clean() . '</ul>';
    return $html; 
}
add_shortcode('wc_vendors_location', 'wc_vendors_location');

/* END */
```

I placed that in my child theme’s functions.php.

To give you a quick breakdown of how that worked, I simply copied the shortcode for showing ALL vendors (See posts above). I then took out the pieces that related to pagination (I didn’t need it, you might).

Then under the – "extract ( shortcode_atts……"" I added – ‘location’ => ”,

This is responsible for the part of the shortcode that can be adjusted.

```
[wc_vendors_location location="filtered piece"]
```

Then I added in the arguments needed for when this shortcode searches for vendors. Under “$vendor_total_args = array…..”

I added:

```
‘meta_key’ => ‘location’,
‘meta_value’ => $location,
```

meta_key is telling it to look at the meta information “location” but not what that actual word is. That is handled by meta_value. That is why both are needed.

Once those are both inserted, I simply deleted the pagination as I don’t have that many vendors, but you might want to leave it in if you need it. If that is the case, don’t forget to add your meta keys and values there.

Ultimately, this ended up working for me. I by no means say I am an expert in php. I have enough knowledge to get me into trouble. So please, if something doesn’t work for you, lets figure it out!

Also, if you don’t have WP User Frontend, you can refer to this post to create your own area to fill out. (http://www.wcvendors.com/help/topic/manipulating-the-vendors-shop-settings/)

I really hope this helps someone and that you all have a great day!

Thanks!
Randall

Comment: The above solution does not seem to work for me. CAn anyone please suggest, if there is anything wrong or missing in this code